# Trying to hidden city a flight but want baggage to arrive at final destination city?

Tags: luggage, hidden-city-ticketing

I'm flying from Auckland airport (AKL) back home to New York soon, but wanted to stop in San Francisco to visit a friend. Since the ticket change fees are exorbitant, I'm wondering if it would make sense to hop off the plane at LAX to hitch another plane to SFO instead? Problem is I'll definitely be checking luggage... could I still hop off and have someone in NY pick it up for me when it arrives? Or are there a gazillion holes in this plan?
Advice on how I can make it to SFO/have my bag make it home and not get sued or screwed would be great!

Comment: If you don't board the LAX-NY flight, your baggage will be removed from the plane.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/63863/32134

Answer (score 2):

Your baggage will be taken off the flight in LAX for customs processing, then you need to recheck the bags for the flight to New York.

If after doing this, you are a no show at boarding time, your bags will likely be offloaded, delaying your fellow passengers and forcing you to track the bags down later.

Comment: Once you have your bags in LAX what requires that you recheck them on the flight to New York? Her bags won't be able to continue to New York but she can make other arrangements to get them there; presumably when she then gets another flight to New York she can take them with here then.

Comment: @DaveD  The OP said she wanted her bags to continue to NY, therefore she would have to recheck them, since they would presumably be tagged already to NY.  But as mentioned that may not work.